# What data structure is best for a few elements, but don't know how many of them?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, tree, nodes

i don't know if this is the apropiated place to ask this but here we go.

I'm making a Tree data structure by hand using and old linked-list handmaded before, it is composed of nodes, which are objects of node class than have inside them three atributes:

- A parent node (1)
- data, which is an Object (the data stored)
- A Child collection(?) of stored nodes (X)

So, which data structure must be used to store the child nodes?

Please have in mind than:

1) Is a tree, maybie use a list is very overpowered, and by instance inapropiate because i'm not gonna store 1000 child nodes there.

2) They are not gonna be to many elements BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW MANY OF THEM CAN BE BY NODE.

3) Define the size of the maxium ammount of childs a node can have in the building can be problematic when using the tree, what's gonna happend if i must add another children from nothing?.

Any comment, suggestion or request of clarification would be much apreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why must a List contain at least 1000 elements to be appropriate? Java's ArrayList initial size is 10.

Comment: You can use ArrayList for storing children

Comment: As people mentioned you can use arrayList, or java's linkedList, both of these implement the List interface. The question you have to ask yourself is this: do I need to do look up's constantly? if so, an arrayList is better as it has better indexing..since it is an actual array. Do you need to insert and delete, not just at the start/end, but also middle? if so then linkedList.

Answer (score -1):

B+ tree should be appropriate because most DBMS software also use the B tree,B+ tree or Hash function and they are capable of storing small to large sets of data items.

Comment: If you feel satisfied please vote up and accept the answer